np.where on a numpy MxN matrix but return M rows with indices where condition exists
I am trying to use np.where on a MxN numpy matrix, where I want to return the same number of M rows but the indices in each row where the element exists. Is this possible to do so? For example:
a = [[1 ,2, 2]
     [2, 3, 5]]

np.where(a == 2)

I would like this to return:
[[1, 2],
 [0]]


There is most likely no such solution without using an explicit for loop. The problem here is that each row in the expected result can have an arbitrary length. NumPy functions, on the other hand, are usually optimized for data of a regular structure (such as your input data). If you are fine with using a for loop, then you can simply apply np.where() separately in each row, of course. For example, you could use result = [np.where(row == 2)[0].tolist() for row in a]

Thank you. I think you mean np.where(row == 2)[1] in your answer instead of np.where(row == 2)[0]

No, I mean np.where(row == 2)[0]; that's because every result of calling where returns a tuple. In this case, it's a one-element tuple and we want to get the first (and only) element.

Try as follows: a = np.asarray([[1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 5]]); print([np.where(row == 2)[0].tolist() for row in a])

Got it, thanks! As a follow up question, can I use this result to subset another matrix (same dimensions as the result of the np.where)? The reason being I want calculate some stats per row (mean, std, etc).

Well that's actually what the result of np.where is built for. If you have another MxN array, say b = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3), then you can do b[np.where(a==2)]. But even shorter, you could write b[a==2].

But this selects all the elements into one array, if I am not mistaken. I still need to have M rows.

I guess, @mozway's answer has you covered :)

One option is to post-process the output of where, then split:
a = np.array([[1, 2, 2],
              [2, 3, 5]])

i, j = np.where(a == 2)

out = np.split(j, np.diff(i).nonzero()[0]+1)

Alternatively, using a list comprehension:
out = [np.where(x==2)[0] for x in a]

Output:
[array([1, 2]), array([0])]

using this output to average another array
a = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 5]])
b = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]])

m = a == 2
i, j = np.where(m)
# (array([0, 0, 1]), array([1, 2, 0]))

idx = np.r_[0, np.diff(i).nonzero()[0]+1]
# array([0, 2])

out = np.add.reduceat(b[m], idx)/np.add.reduceat(m[m], idx)
# array([50, 40])/array([2, 1])

Output:
array([25., 40.])

handling NaNs:
a = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 5]])
b = np.array([[10, 20, np.nan], [40, 50, 60]])

m = a == 2
i, j = np.where(m)
# (array([0, 0, 1]), array([1, 2, 0]))

idx = np.r_[0, np.diff(i).nonzero()[0]+1]
# array([0, 2])

b_m = b[m]
# array([20., nan, 40.])
nans = np.isnan(b_m)
# array([False,  True, False])

out = np.add.reduceat(np.where(nans, 0, b_m), idx)/np.add.reduceat(~nans, idx)
# array([20., 40.])/array([1, 1])

Output:
array([20., 40.])


Very helpful, thank you. As I posted in the comments above, is there a way to select the elements by row of another matrix using the "out" values from your function?

@KidSudi can you give an example? (input + expected output)

so let's say now that b = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]]). I want the mean of each row of the matrix of selected elements using the "out" values, i.e. np.array([25, 40]).

@KidSudi I see, this is not straightforward (could have been another question), it's actually better to use another method without the list of indices, see update.

very cool, thank you for this method. So it seems that we cannot use np.mean here for my example - I was actually intending to use np.nanmean, which may not be possible with this solution?

Well you can, but without nanmean, see update (this should definitely have been another question) ;)

Thank you so much. I agree - should definitely be in another question. I do have another that I will post separately but related :)

I added a follow up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78751642/subtracting-a-numpy-matrix-indexed-based-on-conditions-from-a-numpy-array-and-a

I've actually compared this to a pandas version I wrote, and notice that there are lots of errors, especially towards the beginning of the data set (it's a time series of data with about 100,000 rows and 1,000 columns). Is there something I am missing here? Why would there be such a discrepancy?

is your input a float array?

Yes, the input is a float64 array

then np.diff(i).nonzero() might not work correctly show to floating point arithmetics, you should set up a threshold instead.

import numpy as np

data_array = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 5]])

# Value to find
target_value = 2

# Get the row and column indices where the value is equal to the specified value
row_indices, column_indices = np.where(data_array == target_value)

# Find the starting indices of unique rows
row_change_indices = np.unique(row_indices, return_index=True)[1][1:]

# Split column indices based on row changes
grouped_columns = np.split(column_indices, row_change_indices)

# Convert to list format
result = [list(group) for group in grouped_columns]

print(result)
'''
[[1, 2], [0]]
'''

method 2 (Use np.argwhere):
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 5]])
# Value to find
val = 2

idx = np.argwhere(a == val)

row_idx,col_idx = idx[:,0],idx[:,1]

unique_row_idx,first_occurence_idx = np.unique(row_idx,return_index= True)

grouped_cols_by_row = np.split(col_idx,first_occurence_idx[1:])
print(grouped_cols_by_row)#[array([1, 2], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64)]

res = list(map(list,grouped_cols_by_row))
print(res)#[[1, 2], [0]]

method 3(if you want to use a list comprehension, then it becomes more easier) :
import numpy as np

# Define the array
a = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 5]])

# Value to find
value = 2
# Get the indices of the elements matching the value
indices = np.argwhere(a == value)

# Extract row indices and column indices from the result
rows, cols = indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]

result = [list(cols[np.where(rows == r)[0]]) for r in np.unique(rows)] 

print(result)
[[1, 2], [0]]

